# Android Toast message doesn't show

Tags: android, android-toast

I know there are some other issues regard this problem, however, mine is surprisingly different (at least I think so).

I guess my code is right but I don't have idea why toast message doesn't display. Firstly, I couldn't see toast message in my Fragments. Then I decided to put it in my activity and amazingly it doesn't display here too.

This is code of my Activity which has been extended from FragmentActivity.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "***************************");
        Log.d(TAG, "*** Application started ***");
        Log.d(TAG, "***************************");

        // assign layout to activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = MainActivity.this;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

.
.
.
}
```

Application works fine without error and just this f.toast message doesn't display!
I even replaced mContext with getApplicationContext() and I had same result, toast does not display.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

===============

Update: When I open Toast class there are some red lines. please look at image below

[image]

Comment: I assume you see those 3 logs in your logcat? Try cleaning your project.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.  Are you sure you're not just missing it?  Try changing `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` to `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

Comment: @XaverKapeller, Thanks bro. I remember Eclipse had this problem that we needed to clear project, restart and rebuild again. For sake of experience I did it but still have nothing!!!! When I'm opening Toast class there are some red lines that I don't know is because of them. let me update my question with image.

Comment: Those errors don't matter. They are normal since those two classes most likely have package visibility. You don't have to bother looking at framework classes...

Comment: If you are trying on emulator, then try it on real device else no problem.

Comment: Thanks Osama, I'm on real device. But good point let me test on other device.

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh, Your suggestion was valuable to me. I tested on Android 4.3 It was working fine. My device is 4.1.2 but doesn't display. How come? I'm able to display toast message on my other apps? omg...

Comment: I don't know but sometimes old software becomes buggy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps you have accidentially disabled notifications for your app in the settings? This causes no toasts too.

Comment: Exactly, have no idea when I did it. Anyways, thanks after 3-4 hours rotating around myself finally you told me the reason. Thanks...

Comment: Now I know why my users can't see any hint from my app. I thought that was my fault.

Comment: I disabled notifications for all apps, but I uninstall the app and reinstall it and now it works... ?¿

Answer (score 1):

something may be hiding your toast...so I use this when that appears to be the case:

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TaskEdit.this, "Task Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,0);
    toast.show();
```

You can change the position of the toast location using the various setGravity options available.  Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem. My problem was that a particular emulator was not showing any toast message although other emulators and real devices were. I could solve the problem after closing the emulator and removing folder `<YourUserName>\.android\avd\<EmulatorName>.avd\snapshots`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `mContext` with "this," at least that is how i have been using it... Rather than typing the extra lines of code you can simplify, seeing you are within the `MainActivity` already.